# Recursive call inside an if-else statement

Tags: java, recursion

I can't figure out why my program is calling itself recursively when it's enclosed in a conditional statement. I am working on an assignment demonstrating quick select, a variation of quicksort that lets you find the kth smallest element. I didn't want to be too verbose so I am posting the problem code hoping my explanation can give you a picture of my goal.

In the block of code below, `k` is the kth element I'm trying to find. `l` is the lower boundary to the left of which are all numbers less than the pivot. The idea is to search this side if `k` falls between the lower boundary and `l`.

```
    if (k-1<l) {
        System.out.println("call quickSelect from " + begin + " to " + l);
        if (l-1==begin) 
            {return begin;} //added to prevent random from throwing error
        else {                  
            depth++;
            return quickSelect(arr,k,begin,l-1);            }
    }
```

The problems come when I make the call to `quickSelect` recursively  when `l-1==begin`. I get the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive`
 because I am using Java's random object (which I use to find a pivot within bounds) can only take a positive integer. So this is why I added the conditional statement `l-1==begin` to prevent quickSelect() from being called within invalid parameters. However, I get the same Error! I am surprised this happens because I thought the if-else statement would handle this exception. I would really appreciate any thoughts as to how quickSelect is being called with `l-1==begin`. I have included the entire code for the program below for more details, the recursive calls are toward the bottom.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Collections;

public class quickSelect{ 
    static int depth=0;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int totalDepth=0;
        ArrayList<Integer>al = new ArrayList();             
        Scanner doc = new Scanner("");
//      String smallFile = "proj2small.txt";
        String smallFile = "proj2big.txt";

        try {
            File openSmallFile=new File(smallFile);
            doc = new Scanner(openSmallFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1 ) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (doc.hasNext()) {
            int f = doc.nextInt();
            al.add(f);
        }
        int k=al.size()/2;
            depth=0;
            int p = quickSelect(al,k,0,al.size()-1);
            System.out.println(k + "th element is " + p);
            System.out.println(depth + " recursive calls ");
        }       

    public static int quickSelect(ArrayList<Integer>arr,int k,int begin,int end) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int range = end-begin;
        int j = rand.nextInt(range);
        //int equals=0;
        int pivot = arr.get(j+begin);
        System.out.println("pivot is " + pivot + " at index " + (j+begin));
        int h=end-1;
        int l=begin;
        arr.remove(j+begin);//remove the pivot. Assume no duplicates are allowed
        if (j+begin<k) {
            k--; //shift k left one if index of pivot comes before it because we removed pivot
        }
        while (true) {
            while (arr.get(l)<pivot) {
                l++;
            }
            while(arr.get(h)>pivot) {
                h--;
            }
            if(l>=h) {
                break;
            }
            Collections.swap(arr, l, h);
            l++;
            h--;

        }
        //l is equal to the pivot? 
        //System.out.println("l is " + ((arr.get(l)==pivot)?"equal":"not equal") + " to the pivot");
        System.out.println("k is " + k);

        if (k-1<l) { //l-1 because left shift one after removal
            System.out.println("call quickSelect from " + begin + " to " + l);
            if (l-1==begin) 
            {return begin;} //added to prevent random from throwing error
            else {                  
                            depth++;
                return quickSelect(arr,k,begin,l-1); //array gets smaller k becomes smaller
            }
        }
        else if (k-1==l) {
            return pivot;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("call quickSelect from " + l + " to " + end);
            if (end-1==l) 
            {return l;} //added to prevent random from throwing error
            else {
                return quickSelect(arr,k,l,end-1); //we removed the pivot so l is part of the high range
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

ps sorry for the funny code formatting. pasting from eclipse is not a good idea

Comment: Are you sure there's no negative number being passed into your random function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your file contains zero or only one value, then the value of al.size() will be 0 or 1.

Hence, `k` will be 0, either way, because 0/2 and 1/2 are both equal to 0.

Thus when you pass `al.size()-1` as `end` for the method, in the very first run of `quickSelect()`, it passes `0-1` which is, of course, `-1`.

When you call `nextInt(0, -1)`, an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown, giving you your error.

Comment: Thanks the problem was a negative number passed to random function